# A interesting practice about getchar() function

Tags: c, getchar, console-input

When I do practice  on K&R,I found a very interesting question:

code as follows:

---

```
include <stdio.h>
main()                                                                                              
{                                                                                                   
    int c;
    int bn;
    bn=0;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)                                                                       
    {                                                                                               
        if(c==' ')                                                                                  
        bn++;                                                                                   
    }                                                                                           
    printf("blanks counter:%d\n",bn);                                                               
}
```

---

code function is number of statistical blankspaces

I enter all the words at once ,no use backspace key,it is done.

---

```
$ ./a.out

I have a dream

blanks counter:3
```

---

however,if I use backspace key,what happen may be in input process?

I speculate when a blankspace key is pressed ,getchar() function should get this event,and then perform bn++ ,so even if I later press a backspace key to delete this blankspace ,the value of bn variable is not change.
but the result of practice is different of my speculate, the programe of practice as follows:

the first step:input first blankspace
[image]

the second step:use backspace key delete thie blankspace
[image]
the third step:finish the remaining input of characters
[image]

why result is 3 not 4?why value of bn variable would be changed by pressed backspace key?

please give me some ideas,thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your console is line buffering stdin.  This means that your program will not receive any input until you hit <kbd>Return</kbd>, and it will receive the *edited* text, not the actual sequence of keystrokes.